# How can I enumerate all files in an S3 folder within a bucket?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

How can I get the names and contents of each file in a specific S3 bucket's directory, using the Ruby SDK?

Enumerating the objects in an S3 bucket is straightforward (e.g. `my_bucket`). From the docs:

```
bucket = s3.buckets['my_bucket']
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  puts obj.key
end
```

But now if I want all the files in the directory `my_bucket/some_folder`, I don't know how to enumerate them, and I can't find anything in the docs surprisingly. I tried switching `my_bucket` with `my_bucket/some_folder`, but that gave an AWS error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.with_prefix` method:

```
bucket.objects.with_prefix('some/folder/')
```

You can then fetch them one by one. The above returns an `Enumerator`. If you call `.map` on it, you can access, e.g., when it was `.last_modified`, among other things.

Comment: Awesome thanks Robert! Do you also happen to know if there is a way to get the resulting object's name without the path? Otherwise when you get `object.key` it gives `some/folder/my_object.txt`, when I just want `my_object.txt`. 

Thanks! (I'll accept in 2 minutes when timer is up)

Comment: Sure, if you know the `prefix` (`some/folder/`) and you have the `name` (`some/folder/my_object.txt`), just write `name[prefix.length..-1]`.